# "Move folder" disabled for some subfolders in my Inbox

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

I have three subfolders of my Inbox: 2016, 2017, and 2018 where I store "done" emails.

I noticed that I'm unable to drag-and-drop my 2016 folder, and when I view the context-menu in Office Outlook 2016 the "Move folder" menu-item is disabled, but the 2017 and 2018 folders are fine.

#### 2016 folder:

[image]

#### 2017 and 2018 folders:

[image]

Why is this? And how can I move my 2016 folder?

In the status bar, Outlook reports "All folders are up to date." so I don't think it's an issue with a folder being locked while it's synchronizing.

Comment: 1. Did you try dragging the folder to the required subfolder? 2. Did you try the same via OWA? What were the results for each of them

Answer (score 0):

Normally, Rename Folder, Move Folder, Delete Folder options are grayed out for default folders (Inbox, Sent Items, Drafts, etc.), these options should be available for custom folders. You may first try starting Outlook with **/resetfolders** switch to see whether it helps.

Or, you may consider to recreate the 2016 folder. Create a new folder, move all emails in 2016 folder to this new mail folder. Use MFCMAPI tool to delete the 2016 folder. Then, rename the newly created folder to 2016.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you've set the "2016" as an *Archive* folder (that one for the *Archive* button) and forgot about it (Outlook allowed that previously). Now you need to change your default Archive folder. Unfortunately, recent Outlook versions missing this feature, so you can't change this folder out of the box. In this case, I suggest you to use the free [Set Default Outlook Folder](https://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/OutlookSetDefaultFolders) utility developed by my company to change your Archive folder to another location. This will enable the Move Folder.